# Mount Server Based on Location

Tags: network, afp

On my Mac in System Preferences > Users & Groups I have these two Synology NAS network drives set to mount during login:

- Ryan (afp://NAS/Ryan)
- Shared (afp://NAS/Shared)

This works perfectly at home but when I get to work and turn on my Mac I get this error:

> There was a problem connecting to the server "NAS".
>
> The server may not exist or it is unavailable at this time. Check the
>   server name or IP address, check your network connection, and then try
>   again.

I click OK but this popup appears around five more times before it finally goes away.

Is there a way to avoid this error? For example, only mount these drives if I'm on my home wifi network or using geolocation?

[image: Users & Groups]

[image]